# add and minus messages on member page

Tags: php

i am trying to get a count of unread messages to show when they have a new pm. but it deonst seem to show.

```
    if(isUserLoggedIn() )
    {


        $member=isUserLoggedIn();
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT receiver_id, uc_users.id, uc_users.user_name,pms_messages.is_read,pms_messages.is_read AS unread FROM `pms_messages` JOIN uc_users ON pms_messages.sender_id=uc_users.id WHERE uc_users.id=$member LIMIT 0,1");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id=$row['unread'];
    $war=$row['user_name'];
    $pm=$row['sender_id'];

  if($id  >= '1')
 {
 echo "pms: $war has $pm pms";
    }elseif($id <= '0')
   {
 echo " pms: $war has $id pms";

} 

}
```

Comment: `ms_messages.is_read,pms_messages.is_read AS unread` - strange thing I think

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable!

Comment: You're using a numeric comparison with a string here: $id  >= '1'

Comment: I was trying to add and remove posts from members page with ajax. I did get it to work. 

Found that `$id  >= '1'` was in fact the issue. replacing `>=` with `>` seemed to help but also changed the coding. 

I do not have it no more. I went with wordpress finding it easier then using my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Some things (apart from the fact that I am not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do).

First, you use a numeric comparator with a string:

```
$id  >= '1'
```

Second: You're printing the number of unread messages for each single message. I believe you actually want to count them in the while loop and print them afterwards.